# How to serialize an AVRO schema-compliant JSON message?

Tags: json, serialization, apache-kafka, avro

Given an AVRO schema, I create a JSON string which conforms to this schema.
How can I serialize the *JSON string* using AVRO to pass it to a Kafka producer which expects an AVRO-encoded message?

All examples I find don't have JSON as input.

BTW, the receiver will then deserialize the message to a POJO - we are working in different tech stacks. So, basically it's JSON -> Kafka -> POJO.

Answer (score 0):

> All examples I find don't have JSON as input

Unclear what examples you've found, but [`kafka-avro-console-producer`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/formatter/AvroMessageReader.java) does exactly what you want (assuming you're using the Confluent Schema Registry).

Otherwise, you want a [`jsonDecoder`](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/io/DecoderFactory.html#jsonDecoder-org.apache.avro.Schema-java.io.InputStream-), which is [what Confluent uses](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/7.0.1-post/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/avro/AvroSchemaUtils.java#L202-L206)

Comment: I seen to have looked in all the wrong places.

 AvroSchemaUtils.toObject(jsonString, (AvroSchema) parsedSchema)

seems to be the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1854353 how did you send the message then ?